# WeakMap implementation in EcmaScript5?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-6

I've run across a [JavaScript library](https://github.com/Benvie/WeakMap) that implement a cross-browser [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) in **ES5**.  (WeakMap is slated for **ES6**.)

How can this possibly work without support in the JavaScript language itself?

**Edit:** Just to be clear, I'm referring to a **Weak** Map, not a regular Map.  I tested this project out using Chrome's profiler and the keys are not held by strong references.  They get GC'ed without having to remove them from the WeakMap.

Comment: Consider studying the source code.

Comment: @squint It's doing something fairly deep-- I can't figure out how its not holding a strong reference to the keys.  It's not using Arrays, for example.

Comment: WeakMaps are an ES6 feature that allows you to associate data with an object, but still let that data be garbage collected when either the object -OR- the WeakMap instance itself is garbage collected. It's impossible to do both of these without language support. Most WeakMap shims ignore the part about letting the data be GC'd when the WeakMap instance itself is GC'd.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It took me a while to grok the code, but then it hit me: *the key itself is used to store a reference to the value.*

For example, several layers into `set` it does

```
defProp(obj, globalID, { value: store });
```

where `defProp` has been defined to be `Object.defineProperty`, `obj` is the key, `globalID` is a guid and `store` is a storage object that contains the value.

Then down in `get` it looks up the value with

`obj[globalID];`

This is very clever.  The WeakMap doesn't actually contain a reference to anything (weak or otherwise)-- it just sets up a policy of where to secretly store the value.  The use of [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) means that you won't accidentally discover the value storage-- you have to know the magic guid to look it up.

Since the key directly refers to the value (and the WeakMap doesn't refer to it), when all references to the key are gone, it gets GCed like normal.

Comment: If `obj` is the WeakMap key, and `globalID` is defined on `obj`, I wonder why the `globalID` doesn't show up when using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`.

Comment: i was wondering the same; too bad the lib is so far up it's own behind as to be virtually unreadable. there has to be a simpler explanation...

Comment: figured it out: the lib cheats: it re-defines Object.getOwnPropertyNames(). boo for stepping on existing native functions.

Comment: @dandavis haha i agree about its readability, which is why i posted this question in the first place :)

Comment: It only redefines `getOwnPropertyNames` in order to pull off a WeakMap.  It doesn't break anything, and `getOwnPropertyNames`' functionality is left in-tact. The environment is left fully backwards compatible with ES5 and fully forwards compatible with ES6 WeakMaps. It's a really great idea. I've used it to the same effect in [Secrets](http://github.com/Nathan-Wall/Secrets).

Comment: The shim does not provide one of the main properties of a WeakMap: That the value is held weakly. This shim creates a strong reference between the key and the value ... similar to just setting the value as a property on the key object.

Comment: I'm getting mixed messages here, the answer indicates that it does adequately simulate weakmap and allows its keys and values to be GCed when there's no more reference to the key object. But the @Stef comment says that it lacks one the "main properties". Is this true? Is there a way to empirically test if the objects are really garbage collected?

Comment: My understanding of a weakmap is that it just adds a kind of secret/private property to the object, so it actually contains nothing, it simply mediates this acquisition of the secret property of the object. Thus it allows the key objects to be GCed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't work.

obj[globalId] is itself a strong reference, so it's going to leak.

Unless you have a way of retrieving globalId from the object itself, you can't use the "weakmap" to retrieve the stored value, which defeats its purpose.

WeakMap cannot be accomplished without direct access to GC, so any shim will leak.

Comment: @Stef A reference from the key to the value is normal, that's what you would expect. If the key is no longer referenced by anything and gets garbage-collected, the value is no longer referenced from the "map" either. However, what's missing is that the reference should be removed also when the weak map itself gets garbage-collected.