# Does adding an object to a WeakSet or WeakMap detectably alter that object in any way?

Tags: javascript

I presume that objects added to a WeakSet and/or WeakMap are themselves tagged in some way to indicate membership. If so, is this tagging visible in userland code?

For example:

```js
const go = () => {
  const o = {}
  s.add(o)
  return o
}
const s = new WeakSet
const o = go()
// can I detect that `o` is in a WeakSet, just by inspecting `o`?
```

Comment: Please may you provide a code example to show your thinking?

Comment: This smells like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Not an XY problem: I actually want to know whether the object is detectibly changed.

Comment: No, the object has not "visibly" changed.

Comment: What do you mean by changed? What are you expecting to be affected?

Comment: No, just from looking at `o` you cannot detect wheter it's part of a weakset (or any other data structure) or not

Comment: Why do you want to know if `o` is in a `WeakSet`/`WeakMap`?

Comment: The [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/keyed-collections.html#sec-weakset-objects) doesn't define anything like that: _"The data structure used in this specification is only intended **to describe the required observable semantics of WeakSets. It is not intended to be a viable implementation model.**"_

Comment: @Andreas  This might be relevant to the "tagging" concept: ["This characteristic can be achieved by using an inverted per-object mapping of weak map instances to keys."](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/keyed-collections.html#sec-weakmap-objects). I also note that the spec is explicitly not dictating an implementation, however.

Comment: You can do anything you want if you're the owner of an actual implementation of the spec. But the spec on its own doesn't _define_ anything that would do what you're asking about...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not visible in userland code. You need access to the `WeakMap`/`WeakSet` instance itself to test for membership. This is used to [emulate truly private properties in classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22156326/1048572).

"Tagging" the contained objects at best is an implementation detail (and something like that [was used in most polyfills](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16366000/1048572)), but they might also be implemented in any other way. The only thing on actual implementation in engines I could find is [Sigurd Schneider's talk *Inside V8: weak collections, ephemerons, and private fields*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQsUiqVCJMc).